# SQL: Inner or Outer Join to delete rows from databases?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, outer-join

I have 2 tables:

**PRODUCT:**

```
ID | Price | Status |
```

**ORDER:**

```
Location | Product ID |
```

Product  ID is a foreign key in the **ORDER** table.

I want to delete rows from *both* tables that relate to a Product with a certain status (e.g. Active).

What `JOIN` operation should I use to do this?

Note that there are many more rows in the Product table than there are in Order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to delete a record in Product table you should delete all related records in Order table. So your query will look like:

```
DELETE p
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN Order o
  ON o.ProductId=p.Id
Where p.Status='Active'
```

Comment: Thanks, why does this work better than an outer join?

Comment: Inner join will only return rows in which there is a match based on the join predicate. In this case, what that means is anytime the Product and Order table share an Product ID, a row will be generated in the results to show the match.  But, with a left or right outer join, the result set will retain all of the rows from either the left or right table. That means that you will try to delete rows with null values that do not have to be deleted and it will cost more time.

Answer (score -1):

inner join, you want, only inner join

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: Use this as comment not answer

Comment: Why is it just an inner join? Thanks

Comment: Simple, .... you get an answer the way you ask questions. You asked "What JOIN operation should I use to do this?"  and I gave you an answer. If you want someone to give you code, then say it, but this question you are asking is a covered by basic SQL tutorials. This site is for solving problems and not for teaching people tutorials